# cannot see numbers in uitextfield

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uitextfield

I have a UITextField to enter numbers with width 50 and height 24, but when I enter numbers, the numbers are visible partially(half of a number) after  return the keyboard it is perfect. Following is my code. Any idea please help me

```
    TxtFieldAdditionalFee=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 37, 50, 25)];
    TxtFieldAdditionalFee.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
    [TxtFieldAdditionalFee setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(66/255.f) green:(119/255.f) blue:(169/255.f) alpha:1.0f]];
    TxtFieldAdditionalFee.keyboardAppearance=UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    [TxtFieldAdditionalFee setKeyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation];
    TxtFieldAdditionalFee.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size:12];
    TxtFieldAdditionalFee.delegate=self;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "visible partially (half of a number)". Which part? How does that look like?

Comment: can you make a screenshot of the partially visible number so we see what you're talking about a bit clearer.

Answer (score 0):

remove background color of your UItextfield. make it clearColor and create delegate of textfield up not at the end.

let me know whether is it working or not..!!!

Happy Coding!!!